# Kendo Grid (Any JS Framework) Can I put data in the column header?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I need to get data into the header cells of several columns in the kendo data grid.  It's a timesheet application, and the first columns represent Activities, additional columns represent a two-week period of dates for those activities.

I come from a WPF background.  In the RadGrid for WPF, you could do this:

```html
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
    <Grid Height="32">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="16" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        x:Name="tbDay_0" Loaded="tbDay_Loaded" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource mini}" 
        x:Name="tbDate_0" Loaded="tbDate_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
```

Then, in the tb_Day_Loaded and tbDate_Loaded event handers you basically get the date from a list of dates and populate those text blocks with it.

While this wasn't ideal (believe me, I would much rather do this with data binding), it did work.

Now I'm trying to convert the application to Angular, and I'm using the Kendo grid for Angular.  I don't see a way to do this.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.  This is from the WPF version.  As you can see, the date columns appear after the Comment column, and before the totals columns.

[image: WPF Version.]

Can anyone help me achieve this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just doing this with jQuery.